# Remove duplicates using array_unique and printing the result

Tags: php, function, duplicates, array-unique

I've been searching and trying for hours, I want to look for duplicates in my variables which print numbers and then eliminate the duplicates leaving just original numbers.

Here is what I've been trying:

```
$priceminpps = get_field('price_minpps');
$pricemaxpps = get_field('price_maxpps');
$priceminunit = get_field('price_minunit');
$pricemaxunit = get_field('price_maxunit');

$find_duplicates = array($priceminpps, $pricemaxpps, $priceminunit, $pricemaxunit, );

$result = array_unique($find_duplicates);
print($result);
```

But it doesn't work, can anyone help?

Comment: did you mean `print_r($result)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Double check if array_unique doesn't do what it should.

If it's realy `array_unqiue()` i would generate a new array and push the unique numbers in this new one. You can check if it's already in the new array with `in_array(number-to-check, $array)`.

If `in_array()` doesn't return true, add it to the unique-number-array.

Example:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($find_duplicates as $number) {
    if(!in_array($number, $result)) {
        $result[] = $number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I passing the variables in the array like this: array = ($var1,$var2)? Also, how do I echo this out, every time I echo it outputs an error.

Comment: If you want to add something to an existing array you may use a function, a.e. array_push() or or just (as i did above) "$array[] = $number". The empty brackts [] tell PHP to create/use a new index in the array, as no index has been specified by us.

If you want to see the structure/contents of an array, i would use dump($array), as echo() would only show "Array" as an output.